# (/\s+(\W)/g, '$1') - how are the spaces being removed?

Tags: javascript, regex

`let a = ' lots of    spaces     in this  !  '
console.log(a.replace(/\s+(\W)/g, '$1'))`

log shows **lots of spaces in this!**

The above regex does exactly what I want, but I am trying to understand why?
I understand the following:

- *s+* is looking for 1 or more spaces
- *(\W)* is capturing the non-alphanumeric characters
- */g* - global, search/replace all
- *$1* returns the prior alphanumeric character

The *capture/$1* is what removes the space between the words *This* and *!*

I get it, but what I don't get is **HOW** are all the other spaces being removed??  I don't believe I have asked for them to (although I am happy they are).

I get this one `console.log(a.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));` because the replace is replacing 1 or more spaces between alphanumeric characters with a single space ' '.

I'm scratching my head to understand HOW the first RegEx `/\s+(\W)/g, '$1'`replaces 1 or more spaces with a single space.

Comment: The `g` at the end of the regex says to apply it "globally" and does a "replace all". You noted that yourself. It goes through the entire string applying the regex to as many matches as it can find. `\s+(\W)` matches ` lots` with `$1` equal to `lots` and it matches `    spaces` with `$1` equal to `spaces`, etc.

Comment: because \s+ is matching all the spaces before non-word. And you put the non word space in... https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cs%2B%28%5CW%29%2Fg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your regex says is "match one or more spaces, followed by one or more non-alphanumeric character, and replace that whole result with that one or more non-alphanumeric character". The key is that the `\s+` is greedy, meaning that it will try and match as many characters as possible. So in any given string of spaces it will try and match all of the spaces it can. However, your regex also requires one or more non-word characters (`\W+`). Because in your case the next character after each final space is a word character (i.e. a letter), this last part of the regex must match the last space.

Therefore, given the string `a   b`, and using parens to mark the `\s+` and `\W+` matches, `a(  )( )b` is the only way for the regex to be valid (`\s+` matches the first two spaces and `\W+` matches the last space). Now it's just a simple substitution. Since you wrapped the `\W+` in parentheses that makes it the first and only capturing group, so replacing the match with `$1` will replace it with that final space.

As another example, running this replace against `a  !b` will result in the match looking like `a(  )(!)b` (since `!` is now the last non-word character), so the final replaced result will be `a!b`.

Comment: What a great illustration.  I think I get it how.  Wow many thanks for the clear examples.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Lets take this string `'aaa   &bbb'` and run it through.

We get 'aaa&bbb'

- \s+ grabs the 3 spaces before the ampersand
- (\W) grabs the ampersand
- $1 is the ampersand and replaces `'   &'` with `'&'`

That same principal applies to the spaces. You are forcing one of the spaces to satisfy the `(\W)` capture group for the replacement. It's also why your exclamation point isn't nuked.

Answer (score 0):

List of matches would be the following. I replaced space with `☹` so it is easier to see

```
  "☹☹☹☹(☹)",
  "☹☹☹☹(☹)",
  "☹☹(!)",
  "☹(☹)"
```

And the code is saying to replace the match with what is in the capture group.

`' lots of☹☹☹☹(☹)spaces☹☹☹☹(☹)in this☹☹(!)☹(☹)'`

so when you replace it you get

`' lots of☹spaces☹in this!☹'`